# Show/retain keyboard when password toggler is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, ionic-framework, soft-keyboard

I have the following code, which results in a single password input being rendered with the toggler overlaying the visible input. The `ion-toggle` directive toggles visibility of the two inputs.

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input placeholder="Password" ng-hide="showPassword" type="password">
    <input placeholder="Password" ng-if="showPassword" type="text">

    <ion-toggle ng-model="showPassword" toggle-class="toggle-energized">&nbsp;</ion-toggle>
</label>
```

When the toggler has focus, the software keyboard retracts. The user has to then tap back into the input to show the keyboard again.

How can I programmatically show/retain the keyboard when the toggler has focus? I've tried writing a directive to force focus back onto the inputs, but that feels clunky, and there's the issue of there being two inputs.

**[Here's a basic demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kpyjwy?editors=100)**. You won't get a keyboard in a desktop browser, of course.

Thank you.

Comment: could you create a plunkr here?

Comment: Demo added, though I'm not sure it'll be much use.

Comment: do look at mine answer..I've made some refactoring with solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a directive which will give focus on `password` field when `toogle` button is clicked. Also refactored html of password field instead of two field it will only show one field.

**Markup**

```
<ion-content>
  <label class="item item-input" ng-init="pwd">
    <input placeholder="Password" ng-attr-type="{{showPassword? 'text': 'password'}}" 
      ng-model="pwd" do-focus="showPassword"/>

    <ion-toggle ng-model="showPassword" toggle-class="toggle-energized">&nbsp;</ion-toggle>
   </label>
</ion-content>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('doFocus', function(){
  return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$watch(attrs.doFocus,function(newValue, oldValue){
          element.focus();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[**Forked Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJdXQQ)

**Edit**

Directive has implemented in such a way that we are passing to toggling flag name to the `showPassword` inside directive attribute like `do-focus="showPassword"` so that directive will put `$watch` on the scope variable by using `attrs.doFocus`, watcher function gets fired and when you toggle the `showPassword` button. Basically this inner watcher is `scope.$watch('showPassword'`. Then the function first parameter would be `newValue` which is changed value & `oldValue` means the previous value of `showPassword` model. Here in your case `newValue` & `oldValue` are just redundant they are just not use anywhere, but if you wanted to do something on there change then they could help you.

Comment: This looks good. In hindsight I should've done the `ng-attr` technique. I'll check it out and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @JessPatton Thanks for appreciation. :)

Comment: This seems to be working for me. I'd appreciate some explanation, particularly around the `newV, oldV` arguments.

Comment: @isherwood yes..look at my edit..don't shy to ask question :)

Comment: Thank you. You've stated that the old and new values for `showPassword` get passed into the `watch` function, but how are they being used?

Comment: @isherwood Sorry I missed to mention they are are just redundant now..you can take use of it to performing any operation.. here we are not interested in those values..

Comment: I am tying the same thing but keyboard still retracts. I am using this in an ionic popup. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The cordova keyboard plugin can close the native keyboard but not open it (it can open it on android but not ios). This is a interesting problem sometimes with multiple inputs (mostly on ios) I will have the keyboard close and then reopen. If you only need android you can use this plugin to open the keyboard when the toggle is taped using on-tap="foo()", however as far as I know as of now there is now other way to interact with native keyboard or keyboard events. Unless on toggle tap force focus back to the password input, but like you said that is not ideal: give the plugin a try, maybe you can get it working on both platforms. 
Keyboard Plug-in: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard